# Pixel storage in 24bit BMP vs 256 Color BMP

Tags: c, bmp

In 24 bit bmp the pixels are stored as `BGR` with each color taking only 1 byte each. That can be read

```
for(i=0;i<heigh*width;i++){    // foreach pixel
    image[i][2] = getc(streamIn);  // use BMP 24bit with no alpha channel
    image[i][1] = getc(streamIn);  // BMP uses BGR but we want RGB, grab byte-by-byte
    image[i][0] = getc(streamIn);  // reverse-order array indexing fixes RGB issue...
    printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n",i+1,image[i][0],image[i][1],image[i][2]);
}
```

But in 256 color bmp every pixel takes only 1 byte so How do I read this image and get all the pixel values ?

Comment: 256 color bitmaps, like GIF images, use a "color palette" to map colors.

Answer (score 7):

256 has a lookup table to map the byte values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Google some code: (untested)

http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bmp/parse.c